# Determining TMS format from URL

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, tile-map-service

When I see a MapServer site I usually get deeper and check how it was done. Recently I found on one server where is avalanche map strange tms url. I haven't seen it before.

Can you tell me what is this type?

I know that 14 is zoom and rest is unknown for me.

Before visiting this link you have to visit http://mapy.hiking.sk/?zoom=14&lat=6305837.94292&lon=2194989.75612&layers=00BFTTTTTTFFFFFTT to get cookies otherwise, this url below will not load.

https://mapy.hiking.sk/layers/laviny/14/000/009/088/000/010/772.png

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [JS script](https://mapy.hiking.sk/lib/HikingMaps-3.4.1.js) creating the map, we can see that the layer is of type `OpenLayers.Layer.TileCache`. This tile cache software uses a 7 components URL, with 1 for the zoom, 3 for X, and 3 for Y. Each of the 3 X and Y components contains 3 numbers at most, so the tile `X = 123 456 789, Y=1, Z=10` will be shown as `/layername/10/123/456/789/000/000/1.png`

I haven't found an official textual definition of this, but it corresponds to the [source code](https://github.com/OSGeo/tilecache/blob/master/tilecache/TileCache/Caches/Disk.py) and to several comments.

```
components = ( self.basedir,
               tile.layer.name,
               "%02d" % tile.z,
               "%03d" % int(tile.x / 1000000),
               "%03d" % (int(tile.x / 1000) % 1000),
               "%03d" % (int(tile.x) % 1000),
               "%03d" % int(tile.y / 1000000),
               "%03d" % (int(tile.y / 1000) % 1000),
               "%03d.%s" % (int(tile.y) % 1000, 
               tile.layer.extension)
```